# Smoothing a hall

Tags: modeling

Do you know how I can smooth the hall of left cube, just like the right one in Blender ?

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the *Tools* panel, on the left of the 3D View, click on the *Smooth* button. On the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Normals*, enable the *Auto-Smooth* option and choose an angle of, for example, 20°, it will smooth any angle below 20°.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about auto-smooth!